# How to set timeout hide div after notification showed in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have ajax code like this:

```
   function submitHandler() {
       var date=new Date(),
           formorder= document.getElementById("form-order"),
           pack= $("#id_package").val(),
           namepack= $("#name_package").val()
         $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/index/saveOrder',
           data: {
               pack: pack,
               namepack: namepack
           },
            success: function(msg) {               
               var result = msg;                
               if (result.success=true) {
                   $.gritter.add({
                        title: "Thank You",
                        text: "Your order was inserted. Our team will confirmation your order quickly",
                        class_name: 'gritter-success gritter-center',
                        time : 3000,
                    });
                   formorder.reset();  
   //i want set timeout to hide this '#modal-content' after notification showed.
                   $('#modal-content').modal('hide');
               }           
           }
       });
    }
```

From that's code, `#modal-content` hide firstly before notification show. My question is how to set `$('#modal-content').modal('hide');` to hide after 5 seconds after `$.gritter.add({title: "Thank You"...` showed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the javacript [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) method. setTimeout allows you to execute some javascript code after a specific time period.

Replace

```
$('#modal-content').modal('hide');
```

with

```
setTimeout(function () { $('#modal-content').modal('hide'); }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jQuery, could take the advantage of delay

```
$('#modal-content').delay(5000).modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 2):

Update `gritter.add` with one more event `after_close` and `hide` the modal in after_close function like below. Lmk if it works.

```
               $.gritter.add({
                    title: "Thank You",
                    text: "Your order was inserted. Our team will confirmation your order quickly",
                    class_name: 'gritter-success gritter-center',
                    time : 3000,
                    after_close: function(e, manual_close){ 
                     $('#modal-content').delay(5000).modal('hide');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Oh I just noticed that 5 seconds after close of gritter. Updated with delay for hide. You could use either Shyju or dexherings's line of code in after_close function as updated.